# Cant add API data to list <Class> flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I am trying to make a crypto app. The app gathers data from an API. Ive managed to gather simple lisyt of cryptos, however now i have succeeded in getting the price data (between two inputs of time) through their API as well.

The plan is to use the price data to display a chart. The API gives me a unix timestamp and a price value, which i combine in a map.
I have a model for the date needed for the chart, and a list of the data that comes in via the API. Here is my function:

```
void getGraphData(DateTime range) async {
    int date = range.toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    int maxDate = (DateTime.now().toUtc()).millisecondsSinceEpoch;

    var data = await get(
      Uri.parse(
          "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/market_chart/range?vs_currency=usd&from=${date.toInt() / 1000}&to=${maxDate.toInt() / 1000}"),
    );
    if (data.statusCode == 200) {
      List<dynamic> pricesList = jsonDecode(data.body)["prices"];
      
      var list = pricesList.map((e) => {"time": e[0], "value": e[1]})
          .toList(growable: true);
      for (Map i in list) {
       
        chartData.add(PriceData.fromJson(i));
        print(chartData);
      }
```

So at the end of the function, I try adding the data to a list I have created. This list is a List , with PriceData being a class I have created. Her is the code in the PriceData class, and the list of PriceData.

```
class PriceData {
  final int date;
  final num price;

  PriceData(this.date, this.price);

  factory PriceData.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json) {
    return PriceData(json["time"], json["value"]);
  }
}

List<PriceData> chartData = [];
```

When i try printing the list after running this code, I Lists containing "Instance of PriceData".

```
flutter: [Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData']
flutter: [Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData']
flutter: [Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData']
flutter: [Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData']
flutter: [Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData', Instance of 'PriceData']
```

The URI for the API data can be found here: https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/market_chart/range?vs_currency=usd&from=1545433200.0&to=1640092181.624

Would be really greatful if someone could explain the issue, and give a explanation to how i can solve it.

Comment: When you print the array - something like: `print(<PriceData>[PriceData(), PriceData(), PriceData()])` - you get "Instance of 'PriceData'" because that's what `priceData.toString()` returns. You have a list of data in your array. If you want to see what data you have you can use debug breakpoints or override toString() of the PriceData class to print the values of the the object.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! Have I set it up correctly?

Comment: If it works, then you've done it correctly. I don't see much error checking, there are some efficiencies that could be made as far as number of lines to do the same thing. Otherwise, as far as getting the data into the array, it appears to be working. If you have not already, you should confirm that each instance of `PriceData` contains the data you expect to see based on the API response.

Comment: Do you know why they print like this? Have i done something incorrect? :)`flutter: [(1545436800000,3846.2274979885774)]
flutter: [(1545436800000,3846.2274979885774), (1545523200000,3960.567773408038)]
flutter: [(1545436800000,3846.2274979885774), (1545523200000,3960.567773408038), (1545609600000,3941.617740158326)]
flutter: [(1545436800000,3846.2274979885774), (1545523200000,3960.567773408038), (1545609600000,3941.617740158326), (1545696000000,4021.990255345401)]`

Comment: It adds one group of values every time.